# Interview question: Deterministic time random coloring of a grid with less than three consecutive colors

Tags: random, graph-coloring

Recently got this question from a FAANG interview.

Given the game *Bejeweled*, where 3 or more of the same color either up/down/left/right causes an explosion. The player will then swap adjacent colors to cause the explosion effect. Create a random generator to fill in the colors of the board.

I suggested to generate the board first then if the board doesn't have one possible way to swap for an explosion, we can create that by swapping some of the colors. That was OK.

Then he digs into the random gen part of the question, I then suggest a set and a while loop to generate each color. The set are the colors I don't want to generate. However, this would cause collisions and the random generator may go on forever since it has a non-deterministic time complexity. He wants me to make a random generator that has a **deterministic time complexity** but still random while avoiding the create of explosions on the board.

I got majorly stuck on this and there doesn't seem to be much material on this subject of random deterministic time complexity algorithms.

Edit:

Find an algorithm that generates a random coloring of an NxM grid graph, in which two consecutive nodes of the same color are allowed but not three or more, that runs in deterministic time (polynomial time), and in which more than 2 colors are used.

Comment: The question seems incomplete.  How many colors are possible?  I would suggest modeling this problem as a graph, where the nodes are numbered according to their color.

Comment: Say its more than two colors. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: Then the interview question is reduced to: Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to generate a coloring of a graph at random, where each node is numbered [0, n) and three or more adjacent nodes do not exist, and if so, what is it?

Comment: A board of NxM, randomly generate colors for each element of the board where three or more adjacent colors do not exist in a deterministic run-time. Assume more than two colors can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I have received the following [answer in Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3424624):

> This seems very straightforward.
>
> - Start with an uncolored grid graph.
> - Visit all the nodes in the obvious order, left to right, top to bottom. At each visited node, choose any colour for it that does not complete a three-in-a-row triplets of the same colour.
>
> It is always possible to choose a colour for each node, since there are at most two possible triplets that the currently visited node could complete (with the two nodes to its left or the two nodes above it - the other directions are not yet coloured) so at most two of the k>2 colours are disallowed.